# hitTestObject with Same object, repeatly how to

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, hittest

i am making a game a shootgame, my problem consist in this, my code needs react when the Character hit a tree, in my game i have some tree not one, the trees have the same instance and for that the hitTestObject don't react
This is the code what i try...

```
if(bullet.hitTestObject(world.tree))
   {
       bullet.play();
       die.play();        
   }
```

in my game exist a big quantity of trees so i can't make hitTest for every single one...
In fact that code never going to work for that reason every tree have the same instance, so i don't know what to do!

What i can do to make the hittest react with every single tree in the "world" instance? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function testCollisions():void {
 for (var i:int = enemies.length -1;i >= 0;i--) {
       world.tree = enemies[i]; 
      if (bullet.hitTestObject(world.tree)) { 
           bullet.play();
           die.play();
      }
  }
}
```

Make an array called enemies or whatever you want to call it(if not enemies you have to change enemies in this code to match your array name). Then in the spawning code push the world.tree object into this array.